# Spring 2.5.6 with Java Transaction rollback on Database outage

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I have got an application which has got non transactional code.

Currently in Java 6 and Spring 2.5.6 ( use ibatis-sqlmap-2.3.0).

The requirement is that while processing an enterprise service bean message if a database outage happens the transaction should be rolled back and puts the message back into queue.

What changes should I make can you please give me a pointer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Two Face Commits to integrate Spring with   JMS and a database. We use Atomikos as a transaction   manager. Have a look at http://www.atomikos.com/Documentation/TwoPhaseCommitWithTomcatSpringJMSAndJDBC .

You should consider upgrading your Spring Project. Spring 3.2.x is the lowest supported version.